# React on Rails component not rendering when used inside of `capture_haml` block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, haml, react-on-rails

I have [React on Rails](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails) set up for my project. I have a haml template that renders a React component:

```
-# my_template.haml

%div
  = react_component('MyComponent')
```

Now, if I render this template inside of another template, it works as expected, and I see the rendered React component.

```
-# my_other_template.haml

%div
  = render 'my_template'
```

However, if I reference the component or the template that renders the component inside of a `capture_haml` block, it does not render:

```
-# my_other_template.haml

- captured = capture_haml do
  -# This does not work
  = react_component('EliteSellerBadge')

  -# This does not work
  = render 'my_template'

%div
  -# This works 
  = react_component('EliteSellerBadge')

  -# This works
  = render 'my_template'

  -# This does not work
  = captured
```

In the cases that work, the react component will render inside of a `div` with a unique id like `MyComponent-react-component-0b88d3fe-e457-4bec-b2a1-119097662161`, and will have a `script` tag next to it with the id `js-react-on-rails-context`. In the cases that do not work (inside the `capture_haml` blocks), the div with the unique id is rendered, but it is empty, and no `js-react-on-rails-context` script tag appears in the DOM.

Is it not possible to use a React on Rails component inside of a `capture_haml` block like this, or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been a while but I also had an issue where the contents are on the DOM as described in the question but the react component didn't render on the browser. I think in a situation like this, you'd need to prerender the react component by doing;

```
= react_component('EliteSellerBadge', prerender: true)
```

In my case, the view that had the component I needed to render was added with an xhr request and jquery `replaceWith` method.

Hope this does help somebody.

PS: You might run into issues with prerender if you are referencing global objects like `window` and `document` in your react components.